# Can I tell Mysql which indices to keep in memory regardless of other indices?

Tags: mysql, memory-management, indexing

My database is bigger than the amount of memory I have on the computer. I would like to keep a couple of most used indices in the memory regardless of all other caching.

Do you know if it is possible, and if yes, how it can be done?

Answer (score 1):

for myisam use CACHE INDEX
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/cache-index.html